# Doctrine findby to loop all through rows to show all users

Tags: php, rest, api, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm very new to PHP and having trouble making an API that's essentially taking a GET request and returning all users stored in a table. This application uses Zend Framework 2 and Doctrine.

**Controller**:

```
public function viewAllAction(){
    $restService = $this->getServiceLocator()->get("Rest");
    $restService->auth();
    $business  = $restService->getIdentity();
    $bizID = $business->getId();

    $clientModel = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('clientModel');
    $clients = $clientModel->findAllByBusinessID($bizID);
    $params['client'] = array(
        "name" => $clients->getName(),
        "email" => $clients->getEmail(),
        "phone" => $clients->getPhone(),
        "address" => $clients->getAddress(),
        "suburb" => $clients->getSuburb(),
        "postcode" => $clients->getPostcode(),
        "state" => $clients->getState(),
        "country" => $clients->getCountry(),
    );
    return $restService->send($params);
}
```

**Model**:

```
public function findAllByBusinessID( $business_id ){
    $clientRepository = $this->getMapper()->getRepository( self::ENTITY_CLASS );
    $clients= $clientRepository->findBy(array("bid" => $business_id));

    foreach($clients as $client) {
        return $client;
    }
}
```

At the moment I can successfully retrieve data and return it via rest, but only the first set(row) of data. There are more in the table with the same business ID.

How to I return all rows that have the same business ID instead of just the first one? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your loop in `findAllByBusinessID` method. `return` breaks your loop, so only first row is returned. What do you want is probably something like this:

```
public function findAllByBusinessID( $business_id ){
    $clientRepository = $this->getMapper()->getRepository( self::ENTITY_CLASS );
    $clients= $clientRepository->findBy(array("bid" => $business_id));

    $results = [];
    foreach($clients as $client) {
        $results['client'][] = [
            "name" => $client->getName(),
            "email" => $client->getEmail(),
            "phone" => $client->getPhone(),
            "address" => $client->getAddress(),
            "suburb" => $client->getSuburb(),
            "postcode" => $client->getPostcode(),
            "state" => $client->getState(),
            "country" => $client->getCountry(),
        ];
    }

    return $results;
}
```

But you should split this method into 2 separate functions. One function for retrieving data from database, one to format data the way you want.

Another solution would be to use [Doctrine's queryBuilder](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html) and return data as array set (`getArrayResult()`)